# Magento 2 Hide category from customer group

Tags: category, customer-group

I would like to start a query in the store and then say: If you belong to customer group 2 the category is displayed. If you do not belong to any group or belong to another group, the category is not displayed. Is this possible? Thank You!

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide the category in main menu? or do you have sidebar menu?

Comment: Could you explain the question in more detail, like from where do you want to hide category, i.e. top menu / side menu / show 404 to disallowed groups on pages etc.

Comment: Yes i Want to hide the category in the main menu. And we use the Porto Theme.